# How to get grouped products into collection

Tags: php, collections, magento

I have only grouped products visible. In my specific product collection I filter trough simple products. The results are shown in list.phtml but as simple products. What I need is the grouped Products related to the simple Product instead of the simple one shown in listview. I couldn't figure it out how Magento's catalog handles this.

php:

```
public function getMySpecialProducts($maxlength=null,$minlength=null,$maxwidth=null,$minwidth=null,$maxheight=null,$minheight=null){

        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $_collection = $products->getCollection();
        $_collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('size_length', array('lteq' => ''.$maxlength.''))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('size_length', array('gteq' => ''.$minlength.''))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('size_width', array('lteq' => ''.$maxwidth.''))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('size_width', array('gteq' => ''.$minwidth.''))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('size_height', array('lteq' => ''.$maxheight.''))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('size_height', array('gteq' => ''.$minheight.''))
        ->setPage(1, 10)
        ->addCategoryFilter($this->getMySpecialCategory())
        ->load();

        return $_collection;
    }
```

phtml output:

```
$_productCollection = $this->getMySpecialProducts(
    $range["length"]["max"],$range["length"]["min"],
    $range["width"]["max"],$range["width"]["min"],
    $range["height"]["max"],$range["height"]["min"]
);

$listView = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')
            ->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml')
            ->setCollection($_productCollection);
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($listView);
echo $listView->toHTML();
```

Any help appreceated.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution: 2 seperate collections, 1st simple products -> get parent id's, 2nd get grouped ones depending on id.

following is added to the code above.
php:

```
public function getGroupCollection($groupId){
    $str = array();
    foreach($groupId as $value){
        foreach($value as $id){
            array_push($str, array('attribute'=>'entity_id', 'eq' => ''.$id.''));
        }
    }

    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $_groupCollection = $products->getCollection();
    $_groupCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $_groupCollection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'grouped'));
    $_groupCollection->addAttributeToFilter($str);
    $_groupCollection->addCategoryFilter($this->getFormatfinderCategory())
    ->load();

    return $_groupCollection;
}
```

frontend:

```
// get ID's of Parent Product (grouped products) from 1st collection
$parentProductIds = array();
foreach($_productCollection as $product){
    $product->loadParentProductIds();
    array_push($parentProductIds, $product->getParentProductIds());
}
```

create html block:

```
$listView = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')
            ->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml');

$_group = $this->getGroupCollection($parentProductIds);
$listView->setCollection($_group);

$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($listView);
echo $listView->toHTML();
```

Its sure not the best solution, as for me it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following codes :

```
$collectionGrouped = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'grouped'));
```

or

```
// Get the grouped product a simple product belongs to
$simpleProduct->loadParentProductIds();
$parentProductIds = $simpleProduct->getParentProductIds();
```

or

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'grouped'))
->addAttributeToFilter('size_length', array('lteq' => ''.$maxlength.''))
->setPage(1, 10)
->addCategoryFilter($this->getMySpecialCategory())
->load();
```

Comment: Hello Oğuz ÇELİKDEMİR, thank you for your suggestions. I think I'm on the right way now with getParentProductIds(). Filtering for type_id is not possible in my case, because grouped products haven't any attributes to filter consequently I wont get any results.